# how can i use an HMM to match two sequences when either could have junk rows at the start?

Tags: hidden-markov-model

I have a target and observed list of names. Both are in the same order but there are some missing from each list. I am using an HMM to match the two lists and it works very well in most circumstances.

The problem is where the target list has extra names at the top. I can have as many rows as I like on the observed as non-silent states can loop. But silent states cannot.

I have added state transitions that jump ahead and do allow it to work. However I have to fix how many steps to look ahead; and it relies on having header rows in the observed list.

Is there another solution?

EDIT: As an added complexity it is a fuzzy match. The observed list comes from OCR of poor quality images.